# Cannot load a js file from a different subfolder

Tags: node.js, express, dom, overriding, ejs

This is the folder Structure

```
App
 |
 ├──main.js
 ├──package-lock.json
 ├──package.json
 |
 ├──assets
 |     ├──css
 |     |
 |     ├──js
 |         ├──elem.js
 |         ├──toggletext.js
 |
 ├──models
 |     ├──utils.js
 |
 ├──pages
 |     ├──home.ejs
```

Whenever I try to load the utils.js script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/edit.css">
<script src="/js/toggletext.js"></script>
    
<script src="/js/elem.js"></script>
<script src="/models/utils.js"></script>
```

it deos not load (just says: *Something Went Wrong*) and I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The rest of the files load as expected.

I am using "ejs": "^3.1.6",
"ejs-mate": "^3.0.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"method-override": "^3.0.0",
"mongoose": "^6.0.13"

This is the main.js server file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const methodOverride = require("method-override");

const {Project} = require('./models/project')

const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const ejs = require('ejs-mate')

app.engine('ejs', ejs)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'pages'));


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/a',
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () =>
{
    console.log("Connected to db");
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
```

When I do put the utils.js file in assets/js it loads perfectly

Answer (score 2):

With the last line you define that express should provide access to the static files that are located in the `assets` folder.
With this setting, everything inside of this folder can be accessed via the internet. The `utils.js` is outside of this folder and therefore not available via browser.
I would suggest to put everything that is needed in the frontend into the `assets` folder.